# Running Django from IDLE

Tags: django, python-idle

I wish to test my django project form IDLE shell in windows. 
I run following commands

```
from django.template import Template, Context
t = Template('test template')
```

but I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    t = Template('test template')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 164, in __init__
    if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    self._import_settings()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 59, in _import_settings
    self._target = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 94, in __init__
    raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'C:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\conf' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

**Can you help me out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django needs to load several files like your settings.py.  To help out with this task, Django comes bundled with its own [shell](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) (which can be IDLE). If you have [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) installed, Django will use it instead.

To get to the shell, use the manage.py file in your root directory:

```
python manage.py shell
```

If you still really want to use IDLE completely outside the scope of "./manage.py shell", look at the manage.py file to see how Django loads in all the required files.

As a bonus, look into [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) for [shell_plus](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/CommandExtensions) (it provides some nice additional features like loading all your models automatically).

Comment: Just to be clear, django doesn't really have 'it's own shell', it actually just uses your default python shell, but makes your project modules available to it before it starts.

Answer (score 1):

To use idle from the cmd I did the following in Windows 7:

1. Made sure the **Path** System Environment Variable included the path to the location of idle.py (like C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib). While I was there I also made sure that both python and the Scripts folder are included (the latter contains django-manage.py when installed by pip)

   **Path:** C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib;...

   The paths shown above may vary depending on your installation of python,
2. Optional: to avoid typing the .py extension I made sure the **PATHTEXT** System Environment Variable included the .PY extension.

   **PATHTEXT**: .COM; .EXE; ...,**.PY**

Now all I do while working on the cmd is enter the following to run idle:

- Open a file with idle (being in the same directory):

  ```
  idle models.py
  ```

  this will open the models.py file to edit in idle
- Open the shell using idle (being in the same directory as manage.py)

  ```
  idle -r manage.py shell
  ```

**NOTE**: if .PY is not in the PATHTEXT System Environment Variable you may need to add the .py extension to idle

And there you have it, now you can make use of IDLE. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to run IDLE from Django project directory. If you are using virtualenv:

```
cd /your/virtualenv/directory
. bin/activate
cd project_directory
python -m idlelib.idle
```

Thats all. You can import and run any module and function from your Django project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut and then modify it to have arguments similar to these:

`C:\Python27\pythonw.exe c:\Python27\lib\idlelib\idle.py  -r d:\projects\project_X\manage.py shell`

if you have `PYTHONSTARTUP` on Windows, it will run but then it will start a new process, losing any funcs you may have defined in `PYTHONSTARTUP` file.

Effectively you will see it start up twice below (1st time in green, then red):

**Python 2.7.2** (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type `copyright`, `credits` or `license()` for more information.

*startup.py just ran*

**Python 2.7.2** (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type `help`, `copyright`, `credits` or `license` for more information, 
(InteractiveConsole)

this was true before installing virtual env and shell_plus and ipython. one of these 3 hosed it down - getting garbage in the IDLE console now:

0;32mIn 1;32m1 0;32m: 0m

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are on Windows:

1. Right-click on your IDLE-link to get Properties. There change the target path to be the path your django-project is running in (the directory with your manage.py file.
2. start IDLE
3. Execute

   import os; os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","my_project_root_name.settings")

Now your IDLE has the right context set to know your settings and execute classes in your django-path.

Please tell me if you can think of an even more elegant way.
(Tested under Win 10 with Python 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

If you have idle in your path, you can run:

```
idle -r manage.py shell
```

If you do not have idle in your path, and do not want to add it, you can run:

```
python -m idlelib -r manage.py shell
```

**This answer is based on Alexandro Perez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24968050).*

Answer (score 0):

just create a new file called `manage2.py` (in the same directory) with the same code of `manage.py` and replace the line `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` to `execute_from_command_line(['shell'])`. After that just run `manage.py` on idle. This method has the advantage of using code completion in idle.